# Analyze the purpose of MSSQL error without real-time data

Tags: sql, sql-server, analysis, diagnostics

I am looking for a way how to analyze what caused this errors in a MSSQL server:

```
A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 0 seconds. Working set (KB): 499352, committed (KB): 1024012, memory utilization: 48%.
2021-12-05 18:49:42.63 spid1504    Error: 8645, Severity: 17, State: 1.
2021-12-05 18:49:42.63 spid1504    A timeout occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the query in resource pool 'internal' (1). Rerun the query.
```

This is happening randomly (I didn't found a reason why or when or what can cause this) few times in a month. I already set up some monitoring counters (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/monitor-memory-usage?view=sql-server-ver15) in perfmon but I think this will not solve my problem.

My problem is that I don't know what is causing such SQL memory consumption. I think it is some query from IIS website which is hosted on the same server. It is even worse because it is a production MSSQL server with IIS server and always when this is happening, some admins are going to restart the whole server immediately (because it is PROD and it's need to be working). So I don't have time to look around what is happenning in the server when this occurs. In reality I don't even know (nobody knows) when this will happen again. I need to rely only on historical data. Any thoughts how can I find some reliable information what is causing this?

Server is hosted as VM with this setup:

```
Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (Maximum server memory (in MB): 32768)
16 vcpus
64 GB RAM
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/ (not sure it will help, but it might)

Comment: You already limit SQL Server memory (to 32gb?) That would indicate a QUITE high memory usage from the website - either some "unusual" requirements, EXTREMELY bad programming (loading tables into memory, then filtering - been there, seen that) or - just the need of more memory here. 16 vcpu and 64gb with sql server and iis - not sure that is balanced. It seems not.

Comment: That first aid zip will not help me. When I log on to the server after the server restart there are no reliable real-time information.

Yes I agree it can be really bad programming but I am not the developer. I am just IT administrator and I was asked to find a problem. I was talking with dev but they have not clue why is it happening.

Comment: And I didn't setup the server. Today it was the first time when I saw this production and this server.

Comment: get `sp_whoisactive` and analyse currently active processes. Set it up to record data to table periodically to have retrospective data to analyse and look for high-memory usage and high cost queries.

Comment: If you have a limited user base, ask users what they were doing just before server crashed. Most likely it is some badly implemented report, that when run without filters downloads the entire DB to IIS.

Comment: How complicated is it for an admin to screenshot Task Manager or save the output of `tasklist`, before they restart? They can't expect you to diagnose on nothing. I must say, it's unusual to see this error: clearly no-one gave the SQL Server service account permission to `Lock Pages in Memory`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-the-lock-pages-in-memory-option-windows?view=sql-server-ver15. Bear in mind this means that IIS will get memory pressure, make sure you monitor it for issues

Comment: Unfortunately it is a public web so I don't have option to ask users what were they doing. I already set-up perfmon to monitor the MSSQL and system resources and now I need to wait when it will happen again. From my side of view it is not very progressive to set up only perfmon. Yes the perfmon will tell me some information but I need go deeper to the problem. The idea of using sp_whoisactive is great. Thank you Stu.